# Java has discovered application components that could pose a security risk

Tags: java

I try to execute a applet with **java (jre1.7.45)** but i get the following error:

```
Java has discovered application components that could pose a security risk
```

The only solution that I found is to disable the verification of the **mixtecode(sandbox)**, but this solution seems a bit risky, since it will disable the verification of hazardous components.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your configuration to avoid the message, as described at http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_mixedcode.xml .  Or you can sign the whole thing, instead of just signing parts.

Comment: so i have to sign all jar file that use the applet

Comment: if you don't want to get that error message, it looks that way.

Comment: Can someone help me to find a tutorial for signing an applet containing divers jar files

Comment: Have you looked at the java tutorials? Or googled for instructions?